# Deploying to an Azure Web App via ARM msdeploy/zipdeploy to multiple Sub-Applications / Virtual-Applications

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, webdeploy, zipdeploy

I hope you can help me with the following situation.

We want to deploy an Azure Web App on some sub-applications / virtual-applications. However, what We have researched on the internet has not been very precise with the technique required for this, but I doubt that it cannot be done using ARM.

We appreciate if anyone has information that leads us to achieve the objective or if it is impossible using this technique or it is an Azure bug.

We have tried setting the "IIS Web Application Name" to

1. "[parameters('appName')]/subapp1"
2. "/subapp1"
3. "subapp1"
4. "Default Web Site/subapp1"

We have used extensions:

1. MSDeploy,
2. addOnPackages and
3. ZipDeploy

And the result is always the same, **the files remain on the root of the web application.**

This is the ARM template that we are using:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location of resources"
            },
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        },
        "_artifactsLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The base URI where artifacts required by this template are located including a trailing '/'"
            },
            "defaultValue": "[deployment().properties.templateLink.uri]"
        },
        "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The sasToken required to access _artifactsLocation.  When the template is deployed using the accompanying scripts, a sasToken will be automatically generated. Use the defaultValue if the staging location is not secured."
            },
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "appName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "App Name"
            },
            "defaultValue": "testapp123"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "existingPlanAppServiceName": "[concat('PlanAppService-',uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[variables('existingPlanAppServiceName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "",
            "tags": {},
            "dependsOn": [],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('existingPlanAppServiceName')]",
                "workerSize": "18",
                "workerSizeId": "18",
                "numberOfWorkers": "1",
                "zoneRedundant": false
            },
            "sku": {
                "Tier": "Premium0V3",
                "Name": "P0V3"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('existingPlanAppServiceName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                            "value": "dotnet"
                        }
                    ],
                    "virtualApplications": [
                        {
                            "virtualPath": "/",
                            "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                            "preloadEnabled": false
                        },
                        {
                            "virtualPath": "/subapp1",
                            "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot\\subapp1",
                            "preloadEnabled": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "phpVersion": "OFF",
                    "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
                    "alwaysOn": true,
                    "ftpsState": "Disabled",
                    "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
                    "http20Enabled": true,
                    "websiteTimeZone": "SA Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('existingPlanAppServiceName'))]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "httpsOnly": true,
                "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions",
                    "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '/MSDeploy')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "packageUri": "[uri(concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'),'filesApp.zip'),parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
                        "dbType": "None",
                        "connectionString": "",
                        "appOffline": true,
                        "setParameters": {
                            "IIS Web Application Name": "[concat(parameters('appName'),'/subapp1')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Your code looks good for me as per the requirement. Rather than depending on the `MSDeploy` extension's `"IIS Web Application Name"` argument, you can try setting the virtual application directly in the `Microsoft.Web/sites` resource under `siteconfig`. Have you tried that way. @Frank Leao

Comment: Hi @Jahnavi, Yes, in my example code that I uploaded there are the virtualApplications assignments under siteConfig and they are created correctly in the web application. However, MSDeploy is not deployed on the path of the subapplication, it always hosts the files on the root. In fact, regardless of the value you assign to "IIS Web Application Name", MSDeploy always hosts the files in the root site and we need it to be on the path of the subapplication. Did your code deploy the files to the path of your virtual application or did they also remain in the root? can you share it with me please?

Comment: Understood. But here by default the functionality of `MSDeploy` is to deploy to a single application and it doesn't understand the concept of sub applications. In order to deploy into the path other than root, you need to add a `custom deployment script` property under a site extension resource. @Frank Leao

Comment: Ready!, that's what I wanted to know, thank you very much @Jahnavi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the functionality of MSDeploy is to deploy to a single application and it doesn't understand the concept of sub applications. In order to deploy into the path other than root, you need to add a `custom deployment script` property under a site extension resource. Answer of @Jahvani, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good for me according to your requirement. The issue might be due to the `"IIS Web Application Name"` while deploying the resource.

Rather than depending on the `MSDeploy` extension's `"IIS Web Application Name"` argument, you can try setting the virtual application path directly in the `Microsoft.Web/sites` resource under `siteconfig`.

```bash
"siteConfig":  { 
  "virtualApplications":  [  
      { 
   "virtualPath":  "/add your requirement of virtual path here", 
   "physicalPath":  "site\\wwwroot\\xxxappexample", 
    "preloadEnabled":  true
      } 
   ], 
  }
```

So, defining the virtual application explicitly in the `"virtualApplications"` array ensure that the files are deployed to the correct location after deployment.

*I tried your code in my environment after checking all the above and the deployment was successful as shown below.*

[image]